# aws how to set up ssl certificates for cloudfront distribution, for route 53 hosted domain?

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have registered a domain (my-domain.com) through Route 53 and I have a static website that is served out of an S3 bucket.

My goal is to set up a Cloudfront distribution for my S3 bucket, and then use the Cloudfront endpoint to direct my domain at.

I followed this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiIaoIcoKNY), specifically the Process 2 approach (using an S3 website endpoint as the origin within Cloudfront). It starts at about 6 min 40 secs in the video.

When I got up to the point where they enter the SSL Certificate (at 9 min 15 secs), I selected 'Request or Import a Certificate with ACM' because I don't have any certificate.

I then went into Certificate Manager and requested one. It allowed me to download a file called DNS_Configuration.csv that contained two CNAME records. The status in Certificate Manager is 'Validation not complete' and I am stuck as how to go from here. I have attached a screen shot of this screen in Certificate Manager.

I understand I need to validate the DNS configuration to receive the certificates, but how can I do this given I need my Cloudfront distribution set up as target for my Route 53 record sets? I.e., if I set up record sets in Route 53 (see screen shot), then I need to point it to my Cloudfront distribution. But I cannot create the CF distribution because I don't have the certificates.

I feel like I'm in a catch 22, so any help to get me to the next step from here would be great!

Links to my screen shots:

[certificate manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWydq.png)
[route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO1GP.png)
[image]

[image]

Comment: you are missing the point

Comment: they are different records. posted an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will set up an `A` record and point to `aaabsbsbsbexample@cloudfront.net` in order to get your website domain such as `example.com` served by cloudfront distribution.

In order to validate the certificate request, you will setup a CNAME record in order to confirm the ownership of the domain as requested by ACM. this CNAME is different to your website's domain.  For example the CNAME key will be like `_x1.example.com` and the value be like `_x2.acm-validations.aws`

Comment: Hi Arun- thanks, I will try that. So, first I need to set up the CNAME records per the .csv file, correct?

Comment: yes, you also can see those records in the ACM console

Comment: after you setup the dns. most probably the certificate will be issued with in like 10 minutes in most cases.

Comment: when trying to add the CNAME record for my-domain.com, I get this error: [RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name my-domain.com. is not permitted at apex in zone my-domain.com.]

Comment: i think its because you are entering the key as `_x1.example.com`, but you just need to enter `_x1`. because `.example.com` is already next to the text box. in otherwards you are already inside the hosted zone `my-domain.com`, you dont need to mention that.

Comment: you are using aws console to create the cname correct?

Comment: yes I am using the AWS Console. I have created both CNAME records and the my-domain.com one has already been validated in ACM. the www. one is still pending

Comment: you can also create a wildcard certificate. you can use it with any subdomain. if you want wild card, you can request `*.mydomain.com`

Comment: I think something is wrong with the www CNAME record, still says pending. The name that I added in the box is: _06fe7cf0e263499ecef0eb24a71df9ca.my-domain.com. I did not put the www there. Or do I need to put: _06fe7cf0e263499ecef0eb24a71df9ca.www.my-domain.com?

Comment: sometimes it takes longer.

Comment: you should just put the key `_06fe7cf0e263499ecef0eb24a71df9ca`, mydomain.com is already entered for you

Comment: just added my Route 53 dashboard

Comment: give it a few minutes, sometimes it takes a bit of time

Comment: added a screen shot of my Route 53 dashboard to my original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203873/discussion-between-arun-k-and-ahl).